# Symfony 3 production environment issues

Tags: symfony

My pages only change in dev environment i.e. when i run my app with app_dev.php in url or with AppKernel set to dev:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

For example i have the following twig template:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af8fc051f00e42729a93b0396f37499589ae6a9d

If i somehow modify it (add a div or another tag), the changes wouldn't appear. In order for changes to display i need to be in dev mode. How can i deal with such a behaviour?

Comment: Do you really want to do changes on production environment on friday?

Comment: yes, i do ofc. I need to change my html files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production mode, the cache of the application has to be cleared, otherwise the changes won't occure.

To clear the cache, you have to type in the console, at the root of the project folder (where the folder bin, config, src... are) :

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

At the first visit of the site, the cache will be reloaded that can be (very) long. To avoid this issue, you can warmup the cache, using this command when clearing it :

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

If you have no access to the console on the server, but can navigate to the site folder (the one with bin, config etc...) with FTP in example, you can manually delete the content of the `var/cache/` folder

Comment: Still only works in dev env. When in production gives 500 Error page.

Comment: It somehow deals with 'true' and 'false' args for AppKernel. Probably need to learn more about that.

Comment: A 500 response status code means that there is an error in your application or server configuration. You will have to look into your log file(s) to get the real error message.

Comment: Just another try and your method solved it! Great many thanks.